# Variables overriding not working in Gitlab extended jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repo containing a template that I can't change, there is a build job template that contains:

```
variables:
  FOO: "foo"
  BAR: "bar"

.build:
  stage: foo-build
  script:
    - # Does something here using variables FOO, BAR
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"
```

I have included this template as a project like:

```
include: 
  - project: 'foo/bar/ci-template'
    ref: master
    file: '.build.yml'
```

Inside this file there is a deploy-dev job:

```
deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  needs: [ "build-foo" ]
  rules:
    - if: '$DEPLOY_TO =~ "stage:dev" || $DEPLOY_TO =~ "stage:staging" || $DEPLOY_TO =~ "stage:live"'
```

Finally I have a build-foo job like this:

```
build-foo:
  extends: .build
  needs: [ ]
  variables:
    FOO: "Override foo value"
    BAR: "Override bar value"
  # before_script:
  # - export FOO="Override foo value"
  # - export BAR="Override bar value"
  script:
    - echo "FOO $FOO"
    - echo "BAR $BAR"
  rules:
    - if: '$DEPLOY_TO =~ "stage:dev" || $DEPLOY_TO =~ "stage:staging" || $DEPLOY_TO =~ "stage:live"'
```

The script part is overriding, but it prints values from the .build.yml file, not the overriding values set in build-foo job.
If I use export in before_script it works fine, but this shouldn't be the case? Anyone knows why or how to make it work?

Comment: Do you by chance have these variables set in the CICD settings for the project or inherited from a group or set in a schedule trigger?

Comment: No, these aren't used any where else

Comment: I tried your exact example on my gitlab and it works as expected(job variables override global variables), the echo gave me "Override foo value" and "Override bar value". The variable section in a job is designed to override the global FOO and BAR variables(no need to export variables in before_script). Which version of Gitlab are you using?